# Unable to install more than one Software at once

Tags: installation, software-center

Softwares in USC installs one after the other, is there any way to make more than one sofware install at the same time?

Comment: As far as I know not, this would lead to unmet dependencies.

Comment: why? which dependencies would be unmet?

Comment: Imagine you issue a remove and an install command at the same time.And however,the most time-consuming operation is usually the download.Paralelization will not bring any effort on that as the internet bandwidth is usually a bottleneck.Finally both software installations could make changes to the same configuration files at the same time.Its just not worth it on my opinion.Compiling and installing packages from source, however, would work in parallel ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to install more than one package at once. I suggest you use "synaptic package manager". At the command prompt,

1. sudo apt-get install synaptic

2. sudo synaptic

3. in synaptic, you can choose whatever packages you want to install. All packages will be installed afterwards.