# Why can I install only one software at a time?

Tags: installation, apt, software-center, package-management, synaptic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why the software center doesn't allow multiple downloads?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61719/why-the-software-center-doesnt-allow-multiple-downloads)

I have seen that in Ubuntu Software Center or even when

```
sudo apt-get install
```

is issued,only one package can be installed at a time...

Or suppose there is an update check/install in progress then even if I issue the install command in the command prompt it says unable to lock administrative directory and stuff...

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94266/unable-to-install-more-than-one-software-at-once) question...but that has only solved the problem of how to install multiple packages at a time..

- I want to know why is it like ths??

Even in Windows,multiple softwares can be installed simultaneously(that causes Windows to hang is a different thing :p)...

And also one of the alternate software center, [The Deepin Software Center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/deepin-software-center) allows the installation of multiple packages.

Or as stated in the 1st link,i.e [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94266/unable-to-install-more-than-one-software-at-once) one,it says [Synaptic Package Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/synaptic) also allows multiple packages to install...

Then why is that in Linux/Ubuntu only one application or rather a package can be installed at a time...Even updating packages locks the other softwares from installing..

Why so??

Would like a detailed answer as to is there an advantage in this or why this is a necessity in linux/ubuntu,etc...

Thankyou.. :)

Comment: I saw the duplicate of this question some where in the askubuntu ,please help me to find it :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61719/why-the-software-center-doesnt-allow-multiple-downloads